# XCode-prototype cell, cell identifier

Tags: xcode

I have created three prototype cells in a split view master view controller, each will hold an NSArray. I also gave each cell a unique identifier.
I need for the  cell, when pressed by user to go to its own individual view controller. Please tell me how to code/format the cellForRowAtIndexPath part. I have read many posts saying---now you just need to change the cell for row part--making it sound like something really simple---but code example not given and I just don't see it.

Please Help--been trying to figure this out for hours now!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards you can do it in the storyboard because you are using prototype cells. You can just make a new push to the view controller for example for each of your three cells.  I beleive that the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is more for dynamic cells.